# How to pull django objects based on multiple queries in the view? Django

Tags: python, search, django-models, django-views, logic

I have a search field where the user can search for users' profiles.

This is the relevant part of the view:

```
elif 'q' in request.GET:
context_dict={}
try:
    q = request.GET.get('q')

    users = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=q)  
        | Q(first_name__icontains=q) | Q(last_name__icontains=q) 
        | Q(email__icontains=q) | Q(profile__city__name__icontains=q))

    context_dict['users'] = users

    return render(request, 'proj_name/people_search.html', context_dict)
```

which works fine - if some searches for "Peter" it brings back all users whose first name is Peter. If the user searches searches for "Munich" it brings back all the users in this city.

However, if someone searches for "Peter Munich" it doesn't bring back anything. Is there a way to pull results based on all the queries not one or the other?

Comment: The OR is not the problem; the problem is that each field matches on the whole string, and "Peter Munich" is neither a valid first_name or a valid city_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should first parse your query and extract each field from query like

```
q = request.GET.get('q')
first_name = q['first_name']
last_name = q['last_name']
username = first_name + last_name
city = q['city']
```

then your query should work as expected

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(username__icontains=username) 
| Q(first_name__icontains=first_name) | Q(last_name__icontains=last_name) 
| Q(profile__city__name__icontains=city))
```

Comment: The user will search for random things so the query won't be this structured. But what I learned from your answer is that I could make Advanced Search option where I can parse the query as you suggested. Thanks.